# error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/aria-query/-/aria-query-5.0.0.tgz: tunneling socket could not be establisherd, cause

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, web3js, yarn-v2

can anyone can help me to fix this error i have tried many solutions from stackoverflow to fix this problem but nothing works the error is [imagehere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Jq1.png)

```
PS C:\Users\Nilay\Desktop\Twitter-Start> yarn
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/aria-query/-/aria-query-5.0.0.tgz: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.abc.com".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\Nilay\\Desktop\\Twitter-Start\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Are you using some proxy `proxy.abc.com`?

Comment: @Justinas i dont know that but  how can i check ?